# Problem with adding new item to the list depending on the structure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript

I've following issue. Function which supopse to create new item on the list, adds the row only when the list is situated in the root node (`webUrl = "http://rootserver.com/";`) whereas when it is placed in different location the addition doesn't work (`webUrl = "http://rootserver.com/cases/SLS/SLS-2015-00003/";`). Here is my function.

```
function createListItem(title,hours,server) {
//var webUrl = "http://rootserver.com/cases/SLS/SLS-2015-00003/";
//var webUrl = "http://rootserver.com/";
var webUrl = server;
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(webUrl);
//debugger; 
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TimeRegistration');

var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
oListItem.set_item('Title', title);
oListItem.set_item('Hours', hours);
 oListItem.update();

clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded_Create), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)); 
}
```

Any ideas why is that?

Comment: Does the User have the according permissions to alter the list item? Try access via "...../lists/..."

Comment: You mean _api/lists/getbytitle('TimeRegistration')? Yes, I can retrieve the list.

Comment: hmmm... ok...
Is "cases/SLS/SLS-2015-00003/" a subsite or a site collection? If subsite: Try to reduce the path to the actual site collection.

Comment: Yes, it is a subsite. What do you mean 'reduce the path..'? Could you give an example?

Comment: What errors do you get in the Console? Are really running on http?

Comment: I don't get any errors. The addition just doesn't perform.

Comment: Can separate out site collection url and subisite url ? It will be helpful to understand where exactly list is present.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it works at the root and not at the other location, but I am wondering if it has to do with how you are executing the query.  Just before the query you are calling

```
clientcontext.load(oListItem);
```

This is telling the system to go out and get the data from the server, however the data is not yet there.  It has been a while since I have written any CSOM code, but I am pretty sure you do not need to load into the context a new item before you execute it because it is already there ready to be executed.  What happens if you remove that line?  Does it fail utterly or does it make a difference?

Comment: Well, the whole example is from MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx and there is  clientContext.load(oList); directive. I doesnt work either if I remove this line.

Comment: Yah, it was a shot in the dark.  Thanks for letting me know.  It was the only thing I could see that (to me) looks possibly out of place.  If I think of something else I will come back.  Good luck.